# Cannot solve Python ImportError: cannot import name 'FirstNews'

Tags: python, web, inheritance, web-crawler, circular-dependency

I'm currently making my own project with Python using Inheritance Class between if I select menu from Class A, Parents Class, then moves to Class B, Child Class, and also if I select menu from Class B, Child Class, I'd like to move to Class A. How to solve this problem?

I tried to make these files with Python Decorator, but Decorator can use one file. so I tried to use Python Inheritance to free movement between Class A and Class B, but to no avail.

Main.py:

```py
    # this is the Main.py
    from FirstNews import FirstNews
    from Default import Default

    import datetime
    import random

    random.seed(datetime.datetime.now())

    class NaverNews:
        def __init__(self, news_lists):
        self.FirstNewsSite = news_lists
        self.Default = news_lists

        def __call__(self):
            print("Select the News site that you want to read")
            menu_input = input("Selection Menu")
            menu_list = []
            while 1:
                if menu_input is 1:
                    self.FirstNewsSite()
                    menu_list.append(FirstNews)

                else:
                    self.Default()
                    menu_list.append(Default)
                    break
```

FirstNews.py:

```py
    # This is the FirstNews.py
    import sys

    from Main import NaverNews
    from Default import Default

    sys.path.append('/NaverNews/Main/Main')


    # noinspection PyCallByClass
    class FirstNews(NaverNews):
    def __init__(self, my_choice):
        NaverNews.__init__(self, my_choice)
        self.myFirstChoice = my_choice
        self.mySecondChoce = my_choice
        self.myBackMenu = my_choice
        self.myDefault = my_choice

    def __call__(self):
        print("Select the News Company that you want to read")
        FirstInput = input()
        FirstList = []

        while 1:
            if FirstInput is 1:
                self.myFirstChoice()
                FirstList.append(NaverNews)
                # print("실행")

            elif FirstInput is 2:
                print("Going Back to Main.py")
                self.myBackMenu()
                FirstList.append(NaverNews)

            else:
                self.Default()
                FirstList.append(Default)
                break
```

Default.py:

```py
    # This is the Default.py
    import sys

    from Main import NaverNews

    sys.path.append('/NaverNews/Main/Main')


    class Default(NaverNews):
        def __init__(self, myDefaultMenu):
            NaverNews.__init__(self, myDefaultMenu)
            self.myDefaultMenu = myDefaultMenu

        def __call__(self):
            print("You chose the wrong button\n Would you like to choose again? [Y / N]")
            DefaultInput = input()
            DefaultList = []

            if DefaultInput is 'y' or 'Y':
                self.myDefaultMenu()
                DefaultList.append(NaverNews)

            else:
                print("Shut down the program")
                exit(0)
```

And there are Errors that occurred.

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Python_Class/Web_Crawling_and_ChatBot_1/NaverNews/Main/Main.py", line 12, in <module>
    from FirstNews import FirstNews
  File "E:\Python_Class\Web_Crawling_and_ChatBot_1\NaverNews\Main\News\FirstNews.py", line 3, in <module>
    from Main import NaverNews
  File "E:\Python_Class\Web_Crawling_and_ChatBot_1\NaverNews\Main\Main.py", line 12, in <module>

    from FirstNews import FirstNews
ImportError: cannot import name 'FirstNews'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `FirstNews.py` file is located in sub folder `News`

In `Main` file, try

```py
from News.FirstNews import FirstNews
```

EDIT: i realize that your modules import each other. This is a little bit weird to me, since the debugger would be confused about which one is the main file. And it will be stuck in a loop of importing module. You should consider changing your code structure.

Comment: But I want to ask you one more question, How do I suppose to solve that I want to check that I can't see anything, just can see Process finished with exit code 0. How do I suppose to solve this???

Comment: "Process finished with exit code 0" means there's no problems happened yet, If you use IDE like Pycharm, it's fine. However, it doesn't mean there's no potential bugs. If you want to see something, just `print`. If you want to debug, use debug tools. And if you want to make sure everything's running fine, test it.